# Working with Grid Cells in a GeoDataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, networkx, geopandas, osmnx

I have a GeoDataFrame filled with Points from a given city xy, which I loaded from osmnx package.
If I plot this, I'm getting the Longitude and Latitude on the plot as x and y Axis. (See picture)

1. I want to create a better grid, which is based on 100x100 meters and Not on longitude and latitude
2. I also want to access these grid cells so that I can iterate through them and even index them, example top left grid cell should have Cell_ID = "1". the next one "2"

What I have so far

Packages:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, LineString
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely
import plotly_express as px
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
```

Create the Graph Function

```
def create_graph(loc, dist, transport_mode, loc_type="address"):
    """Transport mode = ‘walk’, ‘bike’, ‘drive’, ‘drive_service’, ‘all’, ‘all_private’, ‘none’"""
    if loc_type == "address":
        V = ox.graph_from_address(loc, dist=dist, network_type=transport_mode)
    elif loc_type == "points":
        V = ox.graph_from_point(loc, dist=dist, network_type=transport_mode )
    return V
```

Enter City:

```
V = create_graph("Enter a city here", 2500, "drive")
ox.plot_graph(V)
# Retrieve nodes and edges
nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(V)
```

Put a Grid on it and plot it:

```
pcproj = ccrs.PlateCarree()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
extent =[16.01,16.10,  48.305, 48.345]  #lonmin, lonmax, latmin, latmax
ax = plt.axes(projection= pcproj )
ax.set_extent(extent, crs=pcproj)

lon_grid = np.arange(16.0, 16.09, 0.01)
lat_grid = np.arange(48.310, 48.340, 0.005)
gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True,
                  xlocs=lon_grid, ylocs=lat_grid,
                  x_inline=False, y_inline=False,
                  color='r', linestyle='dotted')

ax = nodes.plot(ax=ax, edgecolor='k', lw=0.9)

ax.set_title("Gridded Version : Some_City Points")


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Let's say your geodataframe is named `gdf`, what is the output of `gdf.columns`?

Comment: Index(['osmid', 'oneway', 'lanes', 'ref', 'name', 'highway', 'maxspeed',
       'length', 'bridge', 'geometry', 'speed_kph', 'travel_time', 'junction',
       'tunnel', 'access'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: And what do the values look like in the `geometry` column?

Comment: u           v           key
765011      4830405302  0      LINESTRING (16.05975 48.34021, 16.05970 48.340...
            27522173    0      LINESTRING (16.05975 48.34021, 16.05969 48.340...
765093      589078206   0      LINESTRING (16.05990 48.34004, 16.05991 48.34009)
766748      280665222   0      LINESTRING (16.02740 48.32756, 16.02735 48.327...

Comment: There you have the x's and y's of the linestrings. Do you want to extract their points? Maybe you're interested in [How do I extract points from a LineString or Polygon data frame and make a dictionary of point data frames?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238533/how-do-i-extract-points-from-a-linestring-or-polygon-data-frame-and-make-a-dicti)

Comment: Ok, so what I want is to make a grid on this where the lines start from the longitude and latitude points indicated from the x and y axises. Then I want to calculate the the exact center of one grid cell and route the distance to another grid cell´s center.

Comment: This should be stated in your question. Can you update it with these details, maybe a schema explaining it, and some code, possibly with fake data, so that people trying to answer can reproduce at least part of your problem?